# Javascript expression not returning integer

Tags: javascript, variables

```
var canvasWidth = canvas.width - xPadding;
var canvasHeight = canvas.height - yPadding;
var bw = canvas.Width;
```

Why does `bw` become `undefined` when I try to use it?

Comment: Please provide at least the surrounding scope code

Comment: use lowercase "w" on canvas.Width?

Comment: It's case sensitive , so you should use canvas.width

Answer (score 3):

**width** should be in lowercase.

```
var bw = canvas.width;
```

Answer (score 0):

Width should be in lowercase.

And going forward if you are struck anywhere do log the object for a detailed list of variables with in it for you to access them .

For example,

You can `console.log(canvas);` and in the console TAB of developer option (F12 on most of the browsers) you can find all the variables. That way you can cross check.